# Keras Conv2D dimension calculation when padding=same

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Just trying to use Keras but I am a bit confused about the Conv2D function when using padding=same. I wonder if someone can help me to figure out how p (padding) value is set when padding="same"?

Here is a code example:

```python
# X.shape = (3, 2, 2, 2) at this point

X = Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', 
           name = 'apply_conv_2', 
           kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'apply_bn_2')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)

# X.shape = (3, 2, 2, 4) at this point
```

You should read dimensions as (nr_samples, height, width, nr_channels)

If padding="same", height and width will remain the same. But I am a bit confused which value p takes here when calculating dimensions.

For instance, the dimension height should be calculated as:

height_next = ROUND_DOWN((( height_prev + 2xpadding - kernel_size ) / stride) + 1)

height_next = height_prev = 2.
And as seen above, kernel_size = 2 above. And stride = 1.

So.. 
2 = ROUND_DOWN(((2 + 2xpadding - 2) / 1) + 1)

If padding is 2, then the result becomes 5, which is not equal to 2.
If padding is 1, then result is 3 which is not equal to 2.
If padding is 0, then result is 1, which is not equal to 2.

I assume padding needs to be an integer value.

How does Keras calculate padding value here?

Comment: Because your kernel has even dimensions, the padding is likely asymmetrical.

Comment: Great point! I had not thought about it. Using even dimensions in kernels is not common to my knowledge. Can you comment on which  (asymmetrical) shape the padding takes in the above example? Or is it difficult to say sth concrete?

Comment: If padding is 0, the result will be 1, not 0.

Comment: @Kroshtan, you are right. Corrected the typo in the question.